# edit userChrome.css to hide tabstoolbar and nav-bar

Tags: css, firefox, mozilla, userchrome.css

I would like to customize my mozilla interface to display in fullscreen without tabstoolbar and without navigation bar. I use  `./chrome/userChrome.css` like below:

```
#main-window {
   max-width:1920px !important;
   max-height:1200px !important;
}
#TabsToolbar{ 
   display: none
}
#nav-bar { 
   display: none 
}
```

Tried `firefox -P my_profile www.google.com`

Expected: Google page

Result: Blank page, and I've got google page after one click.

Using Microsoft Windows

Comment: is `my_profile` is your default profile set on firefox?

Comment: yes my_profile is my default profile set on firefox

Comment: is that your default profile?

Comment: yes, excuse me.

Comment: then what click you're talking about. for me, that command is working.

Comment: when start my firefox, I've got a blank page... My page appears when i click outside of window

Comment: PS: i'm on windows system.

Comment: Me too, Windows 10.

Comment: Do you have specific config in your "about:config"?

Comment: I have never gone and changed such things.

Comment: Hello @OMPRAKASH, what is your userChrome.css to hide all top bar of firefox?

Comment: I don't think i have that file..

Comment: How do you set firefox in fullscreen without toolbar, navigation bar ....?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing
`display: none` to `visibility: collapse`.

Apparently some functions rely on the nav-bar existing, thus "hiding" instead of "removing" seems to do the trick, atleast it did for me.

Answer (score 1):

On Firefox 110.0.1 the following CSS did the trick for me:

```
#titlebar {
    visibility: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with firefox 86, somehow all pages were blank and I had to edit my `userChrome.css` to something like this from [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/977912/firefox-hide-everything-except-content-area-of-the-browser). Also make sure `userChrome.css` is [enabled](https://techdows.com/2019/05/firefox-69-to-disable-userchrome-css-and-usercontent-css-by-default.html), but since you get a white page it is probably used.

```css
/*
 * Do not remove the @namespace line -- it's required for correct functioning
 */
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* set default namespace to XUL */

/*
 * Hide tab bar, navigation bar and scrollbars
 * !important may be added to force override, but not necessary
 * #content is not necessary to hide scroll bars
 */
#TabsToolbar {visibility: collapse;}
#navigator-toolbox {visibility: collapse;}
browser {margin-right: -14px; margin-bottom: -14px;}
```